# Convert List<Enum> to List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a list of enum values:

```
public static readonly List<NotifyBy> SupportedNotificationMethods = new List<NotifyBy> {
   NotifyBy.Email, NotifyBy.HandHold };
```

I would like to output it as a comma separated list. (EG: "Email, Handhold")

What is the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: wondering whether this is possible using reflection..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
var str = String.Join(", ", SupportedNotificationMethods.Select(s => s.ToString()));
```

You can read more about the `String.Join` method at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx). Older versions of `String.Join` don't have an overload that takes an `IEnumerable`. In that case just call `ToArray()` after select.

Answer (score 4):

you can use linq:

```
string.Join(", ", SupportedNotificationMethods.Select(e => e.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(", ", SupportedNotificationMethods.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray());
```